# MySQL, INNER JOIN a dos tablas pero incluí los registro que se encuentran sólo en una de las 2 tablas

Tags: mysql

Tengo dos tablas de las cuales obtengo los siguientes totales:

```
    MariaDB [finanzas]> SELECT ing_f_pago f_pago, SUM(ing_importe) Ingresos FROM finanzas.ingresos GROUP BY f_pago;
    +----------------------------+----------+
    | f_pago                     | Ingresos |
    +----------------------------+----------+
    | Deposito bancario          | 39350.64 |
    | Efectivo                   | 43250.64 |
    | Transferencia Electrónica  | 64200.00 |
    +----------------------------+----------+
    3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

    MariaDB [finanzas]> SELECT egr_f_pago f_pago, SUM(egr_importe) Egresos FROM finanzas.egresos GROUP BY f_pago;
    +----------------------------+---------+
    | f_pago                     | Egresos |
    +----------------------------+---------+
    | Deposito bancario          |   99.00 |
    | Efectivo                   | 1619.00 |
    | Transferencia Electrónica  |   99.00 |
    +----------------------------+---------+
    3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Lo que intento obtener es:

```
    SELECT f_pago, Ingresos, Egresos
    FROM
    (SELECT ing_f_pago AS f_pago, SUM(ing_importe) AS Ingresos FROM ingresos GROUP BY f_pago) T1 
    INNER JOIN
    (SELECT egr_f_pago, SUM(egr_importe) AS Egresos FROM egresos GROUP BY egr_f_pago) T2 
    ON T2.egr_f_pago =T1.f_pago;

    +----------------------------+----------+---------+
    | f_pago                     | Ingresos | Egresos |
    +----------------------------+----------+---------+
    | Deposito bancario          | 39350.64 |   99.00 |
    | Efectivo                   | 43250.64 | 1619.00 |
    | Transferencia Electrónica  | 64200.00 |   99.00 |
    +----------------------------+----------+---------+
```

Hasta ahí voy se puede decir que bien, pero el problema entonces es cuando no tengo uno de los elementos en alguna de las dos tablas por ejemplo voy a eliminar un registro:

```
    MariaDB [finanzas]> DELETE FROM egresos WHERE egr_id = 2;
    Query OK, 1 row affected (0.15 sec)
```

Pero ahora con la secuencia antes mencionada el resultado es:

```
    +----------------------------+----------+---------+
    | f_pago                     | Ingresos | Egresos |
    +----------------------------+----------+---------+
    | Efectivo                   | 43250.64 | 1619.00 |
    | Transferencia Electrónica  | 64200.00 |   99.00 |
    +----------------------------+----------+---------+
    2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Que me falta para que me incluya el registro que solo se encuentra en una tabla?

Comment: prueba con un join, left join o rigth join. Inner join requiere encontrar resultados en ambas tablas

Comment: Sólo tienes que cambiar el `INNER JOIN` por un `LEFT JOIN`. Esto te mostrará en la columna `Ingresos` el valor `39350.64` y en la columna `Egresos` te mostrará `NULL`. O sea, lo que hace `LEFT JOIN` es mostrar un resultado (`NULL`)  en las no coincidencias, mientras que `INNER JOIN` ignora las filas donde no haya coincidencias en ambas tablas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edito la respuesta luego de los acertados comentarios de @JDev.

En efecto, para resolver el problema necesitarás una especie de `FULL OUTER JOIN`, pero este tipo de uniones no existen en MySQL.

No obstante, hay varias formas de simular este tipo de uniones.

Aquí te dejo una propuesta.

Yo me he permitido trasladar el tipo de transacción a una tabla específica, por parecerme más adecuado. También, he imaginado una tabla `clientes` y he incluido un filtro por ese criterio. Verás que hay dos pruebas basadas en dos clientes distintos...

Al final, te propongo también un modelo basado en una sola tabla `transacciones` que podría manejar tanto los ingresos como los egresos mediante un identificador. Verás que ambos modelos funcionan igual.

La consulta quedaría más o menos así, para los datos que ahora tienes:

```
SELECT 
    fp.f_pago, 
    SUM(i) Ingesos, 
    SUM(e) Egresos
FROM (
        (
            SELECT 
                fp_id, 
                ing_importe i, 
                NULL e 
            FROM ingresos_20180531 WHERE cliente_id=1
        ) 

    UNION ALL

      (
            SELECT 
                  fp_id, 
                  NULL i, 
                  egr_importe e 
            FROM egresos_20180531 WHERE cliente_id=1
      )

    ) t 
LEFT JOIN formas_pago fp ON t.fp_id=fp.fp_id
GROUP BY t.fp_id;
```

---

**Resultado para un cliente con datos en cada caso:**

```
f_pago                             Ingesos      Egresos
------------------------------------------------------------
Depósito Bancario                  39350,64       99,00
Efectivo                           43250,64     1619,00
Transferencia Electrónica          64200,00       99,00
```

---

**Resultado para otro cliente con datos NULL en algunos casos:**

```
f_pago                             Ingesos      Egresos
------------------------------------------------------------
Depósito Bancario                   30,00         10,00
Efectivo                            70,00         NULL
Transferencia Electrónica           NULL          14,00
```

---

#### Demostración de datos

Aquí tienes un <kbd>**[DEMO COMPLETO](http://rextester.com/QGRG74017)**</kbd>, incluyendo la posibilidad de una única tabla, mencionada más arriba.

Espero te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Esto no cumple lo que pide el OP. El necesita que se unan tanto si falta en una como en otra. El LEFT JOIN solo funciona en una dirección.

Comment: @JDev `LEFT JOIN` resuelve el problema... Yo no veo el sentido de tener que mostrar registros da ambas tablas, por la derecha **y** por la izquierda, a no ser que haya un error de diseño.

Comment: No, no lo resuelve, para nada, en el momento en que tengas un registro en la segunda tabla que no este en la primera no va a aparecer y el usuario si lo requiere. Lo que necesita es un FULL OUTER JOIN que en MySQL no existe y tendria que emularlo

Comment: @JDev y... ¿qué problema resolvería un `FULL OUTER JOIN` en este caso, aparte de intentar mantener un muy probable error de diseño o de metodología para obtener los datos necesarios? Yo particularmente sigo sin verle sentido a querer forzar resultados por ambos lados sí o sí.

Comment: Muy simple, si en la primera tabla no tienes registro de Efectivo, tu solucion solo mostraría 2 registros (Deposito y Transferencia), pero el necesita el tercer registro con los valores Efectivo-NULL-1619.00

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, antes que nada una disculpa ya que no me había sido posible conectarme a Internet por problemas de ISP, agradezco la pronta y muy extensa respuesta si, definitivamente será la mejor forma de hacerlo, con la opción de las tablas separadas de Tipo de Moviemiento y Transacciones, gracias a todos por sus valiosos aportes.